# How to add multiple styles to the native element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-renderer2

I'm trying to add multiple styles to the native element in angular, currently using the `renderer2` API.

I've a requirement in which the styles will change dynamically and it can have many styles. That's why I'm not using the class (addClass/removeClass).

constructor(
    private elRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  )

this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, "text-align", "center");
....
...

need a way to add the styles dynamically. something like:
`this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, {style1: value1, style2: value2});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call it multiple times for each style or simply use `addClass` and define styles in class.

https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#addclass

https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#setStyle

Answer (score 18):

**try this**

```
 constructor(private element: ElementRef){
    let el = this.element.nativeElement;
    el.setAttribute('style', 'color: white; background: red');
  }
```